# May I use sf_sandbox directly as my symfony project?

Tags: symfony1

As sf_sandbox has set up the symfony environment, why not develop in the sandbox directly and then upload on to server? What are the disadvantages of sandbox compared with configuring manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no drawback in following this approach. `sf_sandbox` is a pre-configured symfony project. One of the pluses is that is saves you time in creating your project and initializing an empty application (by default this is called `frontend`).

It's more a matter of taste rather than a matter of right or wrong. It's up to you!

Note: If you follow this approach you have to make some initial configuration (steps 1,2,3 would be done anyway if you started your project from scratch):

1. Rename the project
2. Change the `config/properties.ini` file
3. Change the `config/databases.yml` file (by default `sf_sandbox` uses `sqlite` database)
4. Remove the `data/sandbox.db` database file

Comment: I upload sandbox to bitnami AMI on amazon ec2, and go to index.php, but got "500 internal error", do you know what is wrong?

Comment: This could be from anything to nothing. Try to run through your frontend_dev.php controller and see what's reported. And please open up a new question as this has nothing to do with this topic.